# How to detect if the List contains itself in Java

Tags: java, list, recursion, identity, hashcode

From [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html):

*Note: While it is permissible for lists to contain themselves as elements, extreme caution is advised: the equals and hashCode methods are no longer well defined on such a list.*

The problem is that the hash code of a List object is computed recursively.

```
 int hashCode = 1;
 for (E e : list)
     hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
```

The question is how to make my code idiot proof and detect whether a List object (or some of its items or even deeper) contains the List object itself.

How to keep a list of List objects while traversing the List object and be able to call contains()-like method? Is keeping System.identityHashCode(object) and testing against it good enough?

Comment: Do you get to define your own list type? You could detect whether the list is already in the middle of an `equals` or `hashCode` call when another one starts, though getting this to work right in a multithreaded environment can get tricky. If you need to work with stuff like ArrayLists, whether this is possible depends on what kind of elements you need to handle. If a list element has a private field containing your list, you might never know.

Answer (score 4):

`System.identityHashCode` will help, but it'll almost certainly be simpler to use one of the built-in tools to track objects by identity -- `IdentityHashMap`.

```
boolean containsCircularReference(Iterable<?> iterable) {
  return containsCircularReference(
     iterable,
     Collections.newSetFromMap(new IdentityHashMap<Object, Boolean>()));
}

private boolean containsCircularReference(Object o, Set<Object> seen) {
  if (seen.contains(o)) {
    return true;
  }
  seen.add(o);
  if (o instanceof Iterable) {
    for (Object o2 : (Iterable<?>) o) {
      if (containsCircularReference(o2, seen)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

For reference, you cannot depend on `System.identityHashCode` being collision-free.  For starters, you can allocate more than 2^32 objects in a JVM, and there are only 2^32 distinct `identityHashCode`s possible...

If it's not just membership in an `Iterable`, but *any circular reference at all*, that gets harder, albeit doable with reflection.  That said, the existence of that sort of circular reference does not necessarily imply `equals` and `hashCode` won't work; circular references are perfectly okay as long as the references in `equals` and `hashCode` methods are acyclic, and there's no universal way to detect that.